# Does :filter work for older versions of IE?

Tags: jquery

I've got the following line of code in my program:

```
$('input').filter(':radio').change(function() {
```

The problem is that some of the people using Internet Explorer have stated that it's not firing (or the routine that's inside of it is not working).
I know that JavaScript is turn on for their browser because other things are working.

Is there a known compatibility issue with IE and the above mentioned code?
I have IE9 and it's working for me.
I'm loading the latest version of jQuery off Google's CDN.

Comment: In what version of IE exactly?

Comment: It must. That's what jQuery takes pride on cross-browser compatibility. If you have the latest version, then rest assured it does work indeed. Maybe your visitors don't have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: When are you expecting .change() to fire?  It looks like some versions of IE only fire it when the radio loses focus.  This could be your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498987/ie-html-radio-change-event or this: http://norman.walsh.name/2009/03/24/jQueryIE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not heard of any known issues with it, but you could always write it without using filter:

```
$('input:radio').change(function() {
  // your code
});
```

Comment: shouldn't change a thing to the issue, but this is a cleaner and better way to do this! :)

Comment: Hmm. The docs say "Because :radio is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :radio cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="radio"] instead."

Comment: I'll try $('input[type="radio"]').click(function()